# Need a little help, in hiding/disabling the jbutton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jbutton

I am working on an student/admin portal application and I need a little help in hiding/enabling the jbuttons.

- If the user is logged in as an admin, the jbutton should be enabled/appear.
- If the user is logged in as a student, the jbutton should be disabled/disappear.

For example, I have button 1 in Jframe1 and will hide the button in JFrame2.
Please find the code below - the one that is in double asterisk is my code for setting the visibility of the jbutton in frame2 to hide. I have also set the jbutton's variable modifier as public.

FORM 1 - login

```
package testlogin;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

////////////////////////////////
public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public welc welc;
public Statement st;
public int xtry =1,ytry=4,trig;
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst =null;
ResultSet rs =null;


 ///
    public login() {

        initComponents();
         conn=mysqlconnect.Connectdb();    //class connection       
    }

//////////

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        user1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        submitbtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pass1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 300));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 100));
        setName("Login"); // NOI18N
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 230));
        setResizable(false);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("LOGIN");

        jLabel2.setText("STUDENT NUMBER:");

        jLabel3.setText("PASSWORD:");

        submitbtn.setText("SUBMIT");
        submitbtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                submitbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        pass1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                pass1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        pass1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                pass1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(user1)
                                    .addComponent(pass1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88)
                        .addComponent(submitbtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 103, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(user1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(pass1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(submitbtn)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jButton1.setText("LOGIN AS ADMIN");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("LOGIN AS STUDENT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("LOGIN");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 147, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(138, 138, 138)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 48, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(84, 84, 84))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 70, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void submitbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

            String sql = "select *from tablelogin where username = ? and password = ?";      //check Password and Username
         try{
             pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             pst.setString(1,user1.getText());      //gets user text from textbox
             pst.setString(2,pass1.getText());       //gets pass text from textbox
             rs = pst.executeQuery();               //send to query

        if (rs.next()){                            //query will test if username & password == user1 & user2
            if (trig==1){                  //triggers the condition if user or admin
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS AN ADMIN!");
            welc spark = new welc();
        spark.btn_create.setVisible(false);

            }
            else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS A STUDENT!");

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!"); 

             this.dispose();
             new welc().setVisible(true);    
                }
        else               
                if (xtry<=4){                       //condition for number of tries
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD!\n(Only "+ytry+" tries left)");
                    xtry++;                     //increment & decrement for tries
                    ytry--;
                }
                else {                          //dialog exit
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maximum number of tries exceeded. Program will exit..");
                    System.exit(0);
                }                                                                      
                    }
       catch(Exception e){                     

        }




    }                                         

    private void pass1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     

    private void pass1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        pass1.setText("");
    }                                  

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       jPanel1.hide();                                      
    }                                 

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       jPanel1.show();                                      //show panel1
       jPanel2.hide();                                      // hide panel2
       jLabel2.setText("USERNAME:");                        //set text to username
       trig=1;

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         jPanel1.show();
       jPanel2.hide();




    }                                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField pass1;
    public javax.swing.JButton submitbtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField user1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Frame 2 -- welc

```
package testlogin;

import java.awt.Color;                  //import for colors
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;       //import for dbutils/table


public class welc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public String username2;
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst =null;
ResultSet rs =null;




////////////

    public welc() {
        Color color = new Color(0,153,51);  //bgcolor 
        getContentPane().setBackground(color); 
        conn=mysqlconnect.Connectdb();    //class connection   
        initComponents();

    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        btn_create = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_create1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btn_reglist = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 51));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 600));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 600));
        setResizable(false);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(875, 400));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(875, 400));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("PERSONAL INFORMATION");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addContainerGap(374, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "HOME", "ACCOUNT", "SCHEDULE", "LOGOUT" }));
        jComboBox1.setFocusable(false);
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn_create.setText("CREATE AN ACCOUNT");
        btn_create.setEnabled(false);
        btn_create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn_create1.setText("REMOVE AN ACCOUNT");
        btn_create1.setEnabled(false);

        btn_reglist.setText("CHECK RECORDS");
        btn_reglist.setEnabled(false);
        btn_reglist.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_reglistActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 840, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(426, 426, 426)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                                .addComponent(btn_reglist)
                                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                                .addComponent(btn_create)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(btn_create1)))))
                .addContainerGap(110, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btn_create)
                    .addComponent(btn_create1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(btn_reglist))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 409, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(100, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  


    }                                 

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void btn_createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        new create().show();
        this.hide();
    }                                          

    private void btn_reglistActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            new checkreg().show();
            this.hide();
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {



        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new welc().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JButton btn_create;
    public static javax.swing.JButton btn_create1;
    public javax.swing.JButton btn_reglist;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void setOpaque(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is quite confusing, especially because you're not showing how the button is created. However, using setEnabled(true) or setEnabled(false) on the button is what you're looking for.

Comment: button is created by the GUI. I tried using set enabled but it wasn't working.

Comment: Well, like I said, setEnabled(true) will enable it and setEnabled(false) will disable it. If you need more help, provide the GUI code please.

Comment: you may need to `revalidate();` and `repaint();` after changing the visibility of a component.

Comment: Your setEnabled() call looks fine to me. Are you still having trouble enabling it?

Comment: I tried repaint and revalidate '    welc spark = new welc();
        spark.btn_create.setVisible(false);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        '

nope, still aint working. @j4va

Comment: You would have to target the JFrame that you want to affect. If `spark` is a JFrame component, try `spark.revalidate(); spark.repaint();`

Comment: You might also consider creating a constructor for `welc()` such as `welc(int i)` and pass your `trig` variable. Then you could manage buttons from within the `welc()` object, such as whether to create the button in the first place.

Comment: Finally, you are calling `javax.swing.SOMETHING`  waaaaaaaay to often to not `import javax.swing.*;`   This has made your code VERY unreadable and hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: when I used' btn_create.setVisible(false);' in the JFrame2, its working while when I'm executing the command at Jframe1 it aint. I think something is wrong between the connection of JFrame 1 and 2.

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the visibility of a component or after adding or removing a component, you will need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` **on the component's container** (which I believe is the contentPane in your example at least it is for the 2nd window) to re-lay out its components and then repaint itself to get rid of dirty regions on its window.

```
btn_create.setVisible(false);
getContentPane().revalidate();
getContentPane().repaint();
```

Having said that your code could be greatly improved by not flipping windows at the user and instead using just one JFrame and swapping JPanel views via a CardLayout.

---

**Edit**
Here's your error:

```
welc spark = new welc();
spark.btn_create.setVisible(false);
```

You're creating a completely new welc object, called spark, one that is never displayed, and then setting the properties of one of its components, which is working **for that welc object** but this will have no effect on the displayed welc object, since they're two completely different objects. The solution is to give welc (which should be renamed Welc) a public method that allows you to change the state of its button, and then call this method on the displayed Welc object, not a new and different welc object that you create on the spot.

e.g.,

```
// capitalize class name
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   // create one instance only of Welc:
   public Welc welc = new Welc();  //!! added

   // ....


   private void submitbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

      // .... code deleted for simplicfication

            if (trig == 1) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                     "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS AN ADMIN!");
               // !! Welc spark = new Welc(); // removed 
               // spark.btn_create.setVisible(false);
               welc.btnCreateSetVisible(false); //!! add this
            } else {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                     "YOU ARE LOGGED IN AS A STUDENT!");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!");
            this.dispose();
            //!! new Welc().setVisible(true);
            welc.setVisible(true);
         } 
      } catch (Exception e) {
         //!! never have empty catch blocks
      }
   }


   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      //!! never use deprecated methods
      jPanel1.show();
      jPanel2.hide();
      jLabel2.setText("USERNAME:");
      trig = 1;
   }

// ....
```

---

**Edit 2**

Further suggestions:

- On further review, I can see how you'd like to do your logon via a dialog window, but I'd do just that, use a modal dialog such as a JDialog or a JOptionPane. You can use your main JFrame as the "calling" window, even if it has not yet been displayed.
- I recommend that you not have the login window directly modify the main GUI window as that increases class coupling unnecessarily.
- Instead consider creating an enum for your login type, say something called LoginType, and give it all necessary elements, say STUDENT and ADMINISTRATOR.
- Then you could give your main GUI a method, `public void setLoginType(LoginType loginType)`, and in that method, have the main GUI do all it needs to do to itself based on the login type.
- Separate your database code from your GUI code.
- Be sure to do your database code in its own thread, one that is off the Swing event thread.

---

**Edit 3**
For example:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyLogin {
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();

      JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      mainFrame.add(mainGui);
      mainFrame.pack();
      mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      LoginDialogPanel dialogPanel = new LoginDialogPanel();

      LoginType loginType = null;

      while (loginType == null) {
         int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame, dialogPanel, "Login",
                     JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

         if (result != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            // JOptionPane to make sure they want to exit
            // exit
            return;
         }

         loginType = dialogPanel.getLoginType();

      }

      System.out.println(loginType.getName());

      // TODO: check login credentials via database in background thread
      // I'd use a SwingWorker and add a PropertyChangeListener to it.
      // In the prop chng listener, if the worker's state is SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE  
      // I'd show the mainFrame GUI if the credentials are OK

      System.out.println("User name: " + dialogPanel.getUserName());
      System.out.print("Never do this, never change a password to String: ");

      // TODO: delete the line of code below
      System.out.println("Password: " + new String(dialogPanel.getPassword())); // ***** !!

      mainGui.setLoginType(loginType);
      mainGui.setUser(dialogPanel.getUserName());

      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

// parts of my main GUI

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainGui extends JPanel {

   private LoginType loginType;
   private JButton showForAllTypesButton = new JButton("Show for all");
   private JButton showForAdminButton = new JButton("Show for admin");
   private JTextField userField = new JTextField(10);

   public MainGui() {
      userField.setEditable(false);
      userField.setFocusable(false);

      add(new JLabel("User:"));
      add(userField);
      add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      add(showForAllTypesButton);
      add(showForAdminButton);
   }

   public void setLoginType(LoginType loginType) {
      this.loginType = loginType;
      showForAdminButton.setVisible(loginType == LoginType.ADMINISTRATOR);
      revalidate();
      repaint();
   }

   public void setUser(String user) {
      userField.setText(user);
   }

   public LoginType getLoginType() {
      return loginType;
   }

}

// parts of my login dialog jpanel

class LoginDialogPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final String TITLE = "Login Type";
   private boolean loginSuccessful = false;

   private ButtonGroup loginTypeBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
   private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField(10);
   private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);

   public LoginDialogPanel() {
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 32));
      JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
      titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
      add(titlePanel);

      JPanel radioWrapperPanel = getLoginTypePanel();
      add(radioWrapperPanel);
      add(getNamePasswordPanel());
   }

   private JPanel getLoginTypePanel() {
      JPanel radioBtnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
      for (LoginType loginType : LoginType.values()) {
         JRadioButton radioBtn = new JRadioButton(loginType.getName());
         radioBtn.setActionCommand(loginType.toString());
         loginTypeBtnGroup.add(radioBtn);
         radioBtnPanel.add(radioBtn);
      }
      JPanel radioWrapperPanel = new JPanel();
      radioWrapperPanel.add(radioBtnPanel);
      radioWrapperPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login Type"));
      return radioWrapperPanel;
   }

   private JPanel getNamePasswordPanel() {
      JPanel namePasswordPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      namePasswordPanel.add(new JLabel("User Name:", SwingConstants.TRAILING), gbc);

      gbc.gridy = 1;
      namePasswordPanel.add(new JLabel("Password:", SwingConstants.TRAILING), gbc);

      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      namePasswordPanel.add(userNameField, gbc);

      gbc.gridy = 1;
      namePasswordPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);

      JPanel namePasswordWrapperPanel = new JPanel();
      namePasswordWrapperPanel.add(namePasswordPanel);
      namePasswordPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Login Credentials"));
      return namePasswordPanel;
   }

   public boolean isLoginSuccessful() {
      return loginSuccessful;
   }

   public LoginType getLoginType() {
      ButtonModel model = loginTypeBtnGroup.getSelection();
      if (model == null) {
         return null; // nothing selected
      }

      return LoginType.valueOf(LoginType.class, model.getActionCommand());
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userNameField.getText();
   }

   public char[] getPassword() {
      return passwordField.getPassword();
   }

}

enum LoginType {
   STUDENT("Student"), ADMINISTRATOR("Administrator");
   private String name;

   private LoginType(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by your last points about database code? I have a program that is interfacing with a database. Not sure if I did it 'best practice' now that you say that.

Comment: @NonSecwitter: I don't see any conscious effort at creating and using background threads in the code you've posted, so no, you are not currently using best practices. I suggest doing the database coding in a SwingWorker, and then any gui code that will depend on this could be called from a PropertyChangeListener that has been added to the SwingWorker before it is executed. I have examples of this in other answers on this site.

Comment: @NonSecwitter: but that's not the most important part of my answer. More important, you are creating new object, changing their state, and expecting that this will change the state of another distinct object of the same type. Java and OOPs does not work this way. You must call method on the object whose state you need to change. Whatever you do, do **not** use static fields for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my question. I just finished similar project

Comment: @NonSecwitter: your question might then be best asked as a new question on this site. Best of luck.

Comment: True. I didn't even realize there was another way of doing it. I'll start looking into SwingWorker and come back here if I need to.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort of helping me guys, really appreciated it. I'm kinda not me yesterday so what I did is instead of using JFrames, I used JPanels so I have instant access of the variables and objects. Thanks guys! (y)
BTW im short in reputations but I'll vote up your answers later thanks!